# Stop Cron Job inside the scheduler Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, backend, node-cron

I've created a cron-job to run a task and I want it to stop at some specific condition inside the scheduler, but it is not working.

How can I stop cron job inside the scheduler?

Here is my code:

```
// cron-job.js
const cron = require('node-cron');

const scheduler = cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
    
    let result = fetchResultAfterSomeOperation();
    if (result < 20) {
        scheduler.stop();  //------------------------ It doesn't work
    }
}, {
    scheduled: false
});

scheduler.start();
```

Comment: Is fetchResultAfterSomeOperation() async? If so, then it's returning a promise and the ```if``` statement would not execute. If this is the case, use await and make your anonymous function async, such as async () => {}.
Also, make sure the return from result is not undefined. That also invalidates the ```if``` statement.

Comment: No, it is not async...what I'm telling is...the control goes into the if statement but `scheduler.stop()` does not work and I don't know why is it not working.

Comment: Updated the question for easy understanding

Answer (score 1):

**How cron jobs created ?**

Actually, Cron jobs are created from parent process. So parent process can have ability or feature to kill or suspend the child processes. So here node-cron may works in this way.

Now come to your issue, you have submitting cron task using `cron.schedule(time,callback)`. Now callback is going to run on separate child process. So even if you're using `scheduler` object to stop the cron task, it wont work. The `scheduler` can stop the child process from main process (i.e cron.js file).

So I advise you to refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Faizul Ahemed, you may change the code to something like this:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
let result = null

const seachFunction = () => {
   if (!result) fetchResults();
}

const scheduler = cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', searchFunction, { scheduled: false });

scheduler.start();
setTimeout(() => { scheduler.stop() }, 5 * 60 * 1000)
```

The above code will cause the `fetchResults` function to fetch/get data every x time for a duration of y set by the `setTimeout`.

Comment: I've tried with `setTimeout` and it is working. Also as @Faizul said that cron-jobs are executed as a child process but how setTimeout is able to stop the process. Can you explain the relation between the setTimeout and child process?